# texture is different on the geometry than on a plain

Tags: materials

Why my texture is different on a plain than on my final geometry?

[image]

Comment: Texture coordinates are not something to be afraid of. Watch Bartek Skorupa’s video on how to [Manipulate texture coordinates](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=264)

Answer (score 3):

Because it's [mapped](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv/introduction.html#uvs-explained) differently. The plane has a default UV map, which an image-based texture will use in the absence of any explicit UV unwrap you may perform. The other object doesn't.(It appears to have each face mapped to the entire UV space.)

So you will have to [UV Unwrap](https://cloud.blender.org/p/blender-fundamentals/5b27dacf5eab7f020fa599e4) your second object.